# Does tapping into face perception for data vizualization like in the case of the famous "Chernoff face" actually work? What are some notable examples?

Tags: data-visualization

> **Chernoff faces**, invented by applied mathematician, statistician and physicist Herman Chernoff in 1973, display multivariate data in the shape of a human face. The individual parts, such as eyes, ears, mouth and nose represent values of the variables by their shape, size, placement and orientation. The idea behind using faces is that humans easily recognize faces and notice small changes without difficulty. Chernoff faces handle each variable differently. Because the features of the faces vary in perceived importance, the way in which variables are mapped to the features should be carefully chosen (e.g. eye size and eyebrow-slant have been found to carry significant weight).

It seems like the basic assumption Chernoff followed when he was developing his "Chernoff face" looked something like this:
*"If we map the content of one feature space to 'features' in the human face, then perceptually we might be able to trick our brains into using the parts of the brain that are normally used to recognize human faces for recognizing patterns in large chunks of multivariate data, if we present them as glyphs that somewhat look like the human face and by doing so we might be able to make sense of large chunks of data much easier and with basically 'superhuman' speed."*

It struck me as a rather eccentric idea, not like something proposed by a well respected scientist. But reading about it, I became kinda curious: Was Chernoff actually onto something? **How *could* the Chernoff face be improved to make it work as intended? What datavizualization methods have since been developed, that are based on the Chernoff face that do actually work?**

Comment: Read Bill Cleveland's [The Elements of Graphing Data](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Elements_of_Graphing_Data/KMsZAQAAIAAJ?hl=en).

Comment: That's a 300 page book. Could you narrow it down to a few chapters that are relevant to the question?

Comment: The book lays out a set of principles of data visualization informed by psychological research conducted by the author's group at Bell Labs.  Your question really requires an entire book to be answered.  If you would like a shorter answer, then please narrow the question.

Comment: To make this post as helpful as possible to the most people:  Could you provide a reference for your opening paragraph.  Also, could you summarize results from any basic search you may have conducted on studies that have applied the method of Chernoff's faces?

Comment: @whuber "can you meaningfully speed up the process of recognizing/understanding large chunks of data by tailoring the representation to specific sub-domains of perceptions (such as face perception)?"

Comment: That is the entire theme of Cleveland's work.  For an expanded theoretical analysis, see MacEachren's [How Maps Work](https://www.google.com/books/edition/How_Maps_Work/xhAvN3B0CkUC?hl=en).  (MacEachren views a map as a special kind of information graphic and discusses statistical graphics generally in later chapters of this book.)